# How to handle EAccessViolation when closing a Form

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-2010

I'm having EAccessViolation when I close the form of my application and I don't know how to deal with this, I have two units, here is the main unit relevant code:

```
unit MainUnit;
uses
  .., myComponent1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyComponent1.doSomeWork(p1, p2, ..., pn);
end;
procedure TForm1.OnMyComponen1tEvent(sender: TObject; p: Integer);
begin
  memo1.Lines.Add(message);
end;
end.
```

This unit uses another unit is a component class, in which i send a signal to memo1 to show the message, of course using the component event, it's something like:

```
unit myComponent;
type
TMyComponentEvent = procedure(sender: TObject; p: integer) of object;
type
TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
// Properties and events declaration
procedure TPThread.Execute;
begin
  try
    // Create and run some worker threads
    // Wait for them to finish the job
    // This is the last thing to do:
    if Assigned(FOnMyComponentEvent) then
    begin
      FOnMyComponentEvent(Self, p);
    end;
 finally
  //free ressources
end;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.DoSomeWork;
begin
  TPThread.Create(p1, p2 ...);
end;
end.
```

When I close the form before the program finishes its job ( The threads are still working), i get that exception but sometimes, there is no exception raised. Well, when the exception is raised it indicates the line: `memo1.Lines.Add(message);`.
 I don't know how to solve it, so how can I prevent the exception from happening?

Comment: Don't access objects after they have been destroyed. If you want help with how to achieve that, we would want to see some code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are not setting the `MyEvent` event to nil when destroying the Form, eg

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(sender: TObject);
begin
  OtherUnit.MyEvent := MyEvent;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(sender: TObject);
begin
  OtherUnit.MyEvent := nil;
end;
```

Comment: I guess I didn't mention an important thing which is: the other unit is a component and MyEvent is the component event, and it has parameters, I tried not to complicate my question, otherwise I'll edit my question and post the relevant code.

Comment: @Safa: Then edit your question and add that highly relevant information to your question, instead of buried in a comment to an answer. You need to post a full [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, not the small snippet you've posted that is totally without context.

Comment: @Safa: if the component is on the Form then there is no need to reset the event since the component will be freed when the Form is freed. If the component is created elsewhere and the Form is assigned to the event dynamically, then my answer above still applies, just replace `OtherUnit` with the component pointer instead.

Comment: This situation just got worse. Your component is creating a worker thread and then firing the event in the context of that thread. The even handler is trying to access a UI control from outside the main UI thread. You can't do that, and that would easily cause access violations (amongst other kids of errors). Accessing a UI control outside of the UI thread is not safe! So either 1) the worker thread will have to use `TThread.Synchronize()` or other thread sync mechanism to fire the event in the UI thread, or else 2) the event handler itself will have to delegate to the UI thread accordingly.

Comment: And you still have the issue that if the Form is closed and freed while the component thread is running, you still need to unassigned the event handler so the thread will not call it anymore. Otherwise, the Form needs to tell the component to stop the thread before the Form is then closed.